# Spring MVC Processing multipart form data

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, file-upload, multipartform-data

*Using Craig Walls book "Spring in Action, 4th Edition", 7.2. Processing multipart form data*

The code does not run no matter what path you try. I even tried 
`C:\something`. Don't you have to create the directory first?

When I run the code, I get the error below:

> root cause  org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException:
>   Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException: The temporary upload location
>   [C:\Users\jokra_000\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE\base-instance\work\Catalina\localhost\spittr\tmp\spittr\uploads]
>   is not valid

Has anyone successfully uploaded an image file as outlined in Chapter 7? It seems there's far more to it than what's described, as the code Craig supplied does not run. Instead it crashes and will not upload a file.

Any suggestions on how to implement `MultipartFile` and the `Path`?

Craig's suggestion:

in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`:

```
@Override 
protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) { 
 registration.setMultipartConfig( 
 new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/spittr/uploads", 2097152, 4194304, 0)); 
}
```

in `Controller processRegistration`:

```
MultipartFile profilePicture = spitterForm.getProfilePicture(); 
profilePicture.transferTo(new File("/tmp/spittr/" + spitter.getUsername() +         ".jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I did the following:
I changed MultipartResolver:

```
 @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() throws IOException {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
```

and also added the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then imported to the file that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
```