# The spring global cors configuration does not work when the MultipartException occurs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The MultipartException occurs in my web application today. My web application is based on spring boot. But i find this issue during processing the MultipartException. Here is the MultipartException info:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException:
>
> The temporary upload location
>   [C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.3024954041352048338.8082\work\Tomcat\localhost\dutyManage]
>   is not valid

I configed the common exception handler, which will handle the exceptions in my application and return json data.

The issue is the http response does not contains the head like 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. So i guess the spring global cors configuration does not work. Here is the response heads info:

```
Connection:close
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 29 Mar 2017 03:30:51 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

I throw a new RuntimeException in the same method of controller on purpose, the cors configuration works, and the http response contains the head of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

My spring global cors configuration is like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
// ...
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(corsIps)
            .allowedMethods(corsMethods)
            .allowedHeaders(corsHeaders)
            .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

So why does the cors configuration not work for the situation about the MultipartException occuring?

Comment: The error message you cite seems completely unrelated to your CORS configuration. *“Could not parse multipart servlet request… The temporary upload location… is not valid”*. It seems like that’s just a server-side error that you need to fix. And there appear to be some possible solutions in answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845010/the-temporary-upload-location-is-not-valid/38850504#38850504 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307471/spring-mvc-processing-multipart-form-data/38153280#38153280

Comment: I mean that my cite will catch the MultipartException and return a json result to the ajax request. But the callback function occurs error because of the response with out the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to specify custom directory path for temp storage through spring (or server) configuration.

But quick hack would be to create the mentioned directory and provide the read/write permissions as

```
mkdir -p C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.3024954041352048338.8082\work\Tomcat\localhost\dutyManage

chmod 755 C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.3024954041352048338.8082\work\Tomcat\localhost\dutyManage
```

> tomcat.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxx - This will be different on each server.
>   Use this directory name from your server error.